# Max RAM: SIW vs System Manual

Tags: memory, upgrade

I'm upgrading an old laptop for a family member, and I'm not sure how much RAM it can support. According to the manual, it can support 1 GB per slot, for a total of 2 GB. However, when I ran [SIW (System Information for Windows)](https://www.gtopala.com/), it claimed the computer supported 2 GB per slot, for a total of 4 GB.

Which should I go with, what the manual says or what SIW says. Thank you for your help.

~Chris

Comment: Could you Post the Laptop model?

Comment: It's a Dell Inspiron 6000.

Comment: The manual will state what the vendor guarantees to work. At times, this even depends on specific RAM chips, e.g. due to power consumption. Other configurations may partially work (e.g. unsupported power modes) but chances aren't very high. In other words, if you don't find success stories on the web beyond what the manual says, you shouldn't expect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Taking a Look. It Looks like The max is **2GB**.

Either **2GB** stick in one slot or **1GB** and **1GB**.

Going against the Manufacturer maximum supported will most likely cause it not to boot.

Saying this always go with the **Manual** on the hardware not what the software tells you unless there was a bios update for the PC which I do not believe there was one for the model you listed.